# Adding fadeOut function before fading In new classes in this script im using as filter for multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this script to filter elemets based on class. Currently it stops previous function and fade in new class, i need it to stop, fade out everything (it can be specific class, eg. .all) then fadein as it is now. I am not able to add thet fade out to the script. Thanks for help.

Heres the script:

```
<script>
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=radio]', 'change', update);
update();
function update() {
    var $lis = $('.results > div'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');
    if ($checked.length) {
        var selector = $checked.map(function () {
            return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join('');

        $lis.hide().filter(selector).stop().fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc');

    } else {
        $lis.stop().fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: not totally clear what problem is but try `.stop(true,true)`

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear enough. I need to fadeOut everything before it starts to fadeIn selector. Currently its sharp cut from 100%opacity to starting fadeing selector, and i want to smoothly fade out current (or specific class) and than fade in this one.